# Connection between one record and table - MS Access

Tags: database, ms-access

I have problem with my database in MS Access.
I want to choose one option (record) from table (for example name: John) and in next step have a connection with another table. When I choose another option (name: Peter) i have connection with another table. And this is important for me to have this connection between one record from table with another table.
For example: Table "Name" = ["John", "Peter", "Kate"] and tables "Info about John", "Info about Peter", "Info about Kate". And when I would choose John, go to "Info about John". [image]

Comment: Why would you have 3 related tables instead of 1? Why would each name have its own related table? What if you have thousands of names? Can't have thousands of tables.

Comment: This is example. I search solution for create a relationship between a single record in a one table and another table.

Comment: For example: Table "Name" = ["John", "Peter", "Kate"] and tables "Info about John", "Info about Peter", "Info about Kate". And when I would choose John, go to "Info about John".

Comment: My comment still applies. Your concept is bad design. Have you studied any tutorials on database concepts?

Comment: I know that this concept isn't good but I want to explain my problem. Options depend on choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been suggested in the comments, what you are proposing is not good database design.

Your table layout should be:

- tblPerson: PersonID (Autonumber, Primary key), PersonName (Text);
- tblPersonExtra: PersonExtraID (Autonumber, Primary key), PersonID (Number, Foreign key from tblPerson), PersonExtra (Text).

This assumes that there is a requirement for a 1 to many relationship between data to be held in the two tables. If there is a 1 to 1 relationship (for example, PersonName is "Peter", and "PersonExtra" is actually their date of birth, then there would be no real reason to split into a second table.

You really should read up on how to design a relational database.

Regards,